# How to create a wind map from wrfout in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, wrf-model

I would like to create a wind direction map in GRASS GIS using wind U-velocity and V-velocity, which are outputs from the weather model WRF.
I tried to create a wind direction map with the command d.rast.arrow (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/d.rast.arrow.html)
However, U velocity is divided into a 250 x 229 grid and V velocity into a 249 x 230 grid, which cannot be calculated with r.mapcalc because they do not have the same number of grids.(See figure)
[image]
Red and blue dots mark the center of each grid
In such a case, how can I make the calculation with the same number of grids?

Comment: Why two different grids? Can't you export u and v from WRF on the same grid? (Sorry for the annoying question).

Comment: Also, in case you did not know: `d.rast.arrow` takes an aspect grid as input. So you'll have to do some manipulation on the u and v vectors to get the overall wind direction, then `r.slope.aspect` to derive the aspect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The trouble is that the wrf settings generate U and V on different grids.
I was not familiar with the d.slope.aspect command, so I will check it out.

Comment: I thought that WRF outputs a single netcdf file with all variables on the same grid.??

Comment: I managed to align the U and V grids by averaging the grids in the U and V directions, respectively.
How to derive the raster gradient with r.slope.aspect and r.rast.arrow https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/d.rast.arrow.html
On the above page
r.mapcalc "magnitude = sqrt(U_map^2 + V_map^2)"
r.mapcalc "direction = atan(U_map, V_map)"
d.rast.arrow map=direction type=grass magnitude_map=magnitude skip=3 grid=none
Is there any difference between the method using r.mapcalc called
(This is going to be another question, so I'll start another thread)